# Arduino OBD connection

Tags: arduino-nano

I am using this code on a arduino nano and works fine.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);           // select the pins used on the LCD panel


#include <OBD2UART.h>

COBD obd;

void setup()
{

  // start communication with OBD-II UART adapter
  obd.begin();
  lcd.begin(16, 2); 
  // initiate OBD-II connection until success
  while (!obd.init());  
}

void loop()
{
  int value;
  obd.readPID(PID_RPM, value);
  int value2;
  obd.readPID(PID_COOLANT_TEMP, value2);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("RPM = ");
  lcd.print(value);
  lcd.print("     ");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("ECT = ");
  lcd.print(value2);
  lcd.print("     ");
    }
```

But if OBD is not connected, then it's get stuck in the setup.
What I want to do is to go over setup even if obd is not connected, and try connect to OBD meanwhile...something like display "Connecting..." on first row and count something on second...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while()` loop in `setup()` is what gets hung up. Instead of calling `odb.init()` until it returns `true`, just call it once just to get it initiated, then call/check in `loop()` and react accordingly:

```
void setup()
{
  // start communication with OBD-II UART adapter
  obd.begin();
  lcd.begin(16, 2); 
  // initiate OBD-II connection once
  obd.init()
}

void loop()
{
  static int error_count;
  if (!obd.init()) {
    // Not connected
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Connecting");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Count: ");
    lcd.print(error_count);
    error_count++;`
  } else {
    int value;
    int value2;

    obd.readPID(PID_RPM, value);
    obd.readPID(PID_COOLANT_TEMP, value2);
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("RPM = ");
    lcd.print(value);
    lcd.print("     ");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("ECT = ");
    lcd.print(value2);
    lcd.print("     ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is working but seems there is a big timeout till it receive the status of the obd if is not init yet.